# Como ver la foreign key que tiene una tabla

Tags: mysql

quería preguntar si alguien sabe como ver en mysql las foreign key que tiene una tabla,por que parece ser que con show create table no se ve.

Answer (score 3):

A través de MySQL desde la línea de comandos, si la relación se creó de manera exitosa solo basta llevar a cabo el siguiente comando sobre la tabla que las tiene incluidas:

```
DESCRIBE TABLE posts;
```

Recuerda es muy importante que por convensión tu llave foránea sea del modo: `nombretabla_id`, es decir `usuario_id` pues esto también te ayudará a tener claro cuales son tus llaves foráneas.

Así como en la columna `KEY` la identificas por que tiene lo siguiente *PRI* de PRIMARY KEY

Imagina el siguiente escenario, tienes una tabla usuarios y tienes otra roles:

```
CREATE TABLE roles(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    rol_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    rol_status TINYINT(1) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    status_user TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    rol_id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_users_roles FOREIGN KEY(rol_id) REFERENCES roles(id)
);
```

Entonces si creas estas tablas y posterior haces el comando que ya te escribí te saldrá:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese campo que dice `rol_id` es mi llave foránea

Comment: Maravillosamente explicado,muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar de primera intención un **`describe`** de tu table, en donde aparecerán las columnas, el tipo y las claves (si es primary o foreign):

```
describe tu_tabla;
```

Otra manera es consultar el script de construcción con:

```
show create table tu_tabla;
```

para determinar a que tablas estas haciendo referencia.

O hacer un query al `information_schema` de mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
AND information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'tu_db'
AND information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_NAME = 'tu_tabla';
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias,muy bien explicado.